# Apache Commons FTP client: Connect from fixed local port number

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I'm going to develop a FTP client between two machines which due to security reasons there is a restrict firewall between them. The firewall only accept connections to already defined ports on both server and client and there is no possibility to open a port range. But I can not bind my client and server to negotiate with specific ports. For example I always want to upload one file from port 50000 on my local to port 21 on the FTP server. How I can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`connect` method overload that takes `localPort` parameter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#connect-java.lang.String-int-java.net.InetAddress-int-) (the method is inherited from `SocketClient`:

```
public void connect(InetAddress host, int port,
                    InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

Pay attention to `localAddr` if you have more the one IP assigned.